# Significant Node.js vs Python 3 execution time difference for the same code?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, performance, runtime

I was working on a solution for a problem from a practice website and got the correct answer. I had written my solution in JavaScript/ES6 (Node.js) and its execution time was about `870ms`. Here's the code that I wrote:

```js
console.time('runtime')
const isPrime = num => {
    if (num < 0) return false
    for (let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
        if (num % i === 0) return false
    return num !== 1
}

let sideLength = 7
let ratio = 100
let gap = 2
let progress = 1
let primes = 0
let count = 2

for (let i = 3; ratio >= 10; i += gap) {
    const iRoot = Math.sqrt(i)
    if (iRoot % 2 === 1) {
        ratio = (primes / count) * 100
        sideLength = iRoot
    }
    const curProgress = progress % 4
    if (curProgress === 0)
        gap += 2
    progress++
    if (isPrime(i))
        primes++
    count++
}

console.log(sideLength)
console.timeEnd('runtime')
```

As a challenge for myself, I wanted to rewrite the same logic in Python 3. I tried to replicate the same logic as best I could between both programs. Its execution time was significantly slower, though. Around `19200ms`! Approximately 22 times slower than the JavaScript version! I ended up with this as the result for the Python 3 version:

```py
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(num):
    if num < 0:
        return False
    s = sqrt(num)
    for i in range(2, int(s) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return num != 1

side_length = 7
ratio = 100
gap = 2
progress = 1
primes = 0
count = 2
i = 3

while ratio >= 10:
    root_i = sqrt(i)
    if root_i % 2 == 1:
        ratio = (primes / count) * 100
        side_length = root_i
    current_progress = progress % 4
    if current_progress == 0:
        gap += 2
    progress += 1
    if is_prime(i):
        primes += 1
    count += 1
    i += gap

print(int(side_length))
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something pretty obvious or if there's a significant difference in how similar functions work in the background when comparing JavaScript and Python. Any help with understanding why this performance difference occurs would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Note on how I measured execution times**:

For Python, I used the `%timeit` [magic function](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) in [iPython](https://ipython.org/) in conjunction with executing from the file with `%run`.

For the JavaScript version, I used the [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) function by putting `console.time('runtime')` and `console.timeEnd('runtime')` at the top and bottom of the file respectively.

Comment: How did u got the execution time

Comment: @KerryGougeon I'll edit that in at the bottom of my post to clarify.

Comment: I think this code could run in Python 2 as well, so I would double check that you ran it with the Python 3 interpreter. Using the range function in Python 2 could be something that would bloat the execution time significantly.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer I'm positive that I ran it with the Python 3 interpreter. If I run it with the Python 2 interpreter, it immediately prints out `3` as the result. Not really sure why, but it definitely only works with Python 3.

Comment: You're right. I didn't catch that `primes / count` would be doing integer division in Python 2 earlier today.